# Как указать пути до исходников в Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qtcreator

Есть динамическая библиотека собранная с отладочной информацией и исходники к ней. При отладке приложения которое использует эту библиотеку QtCreator показывает символы из этой библиотеки, но как их сопоставить с исходниками?

Comment: Он показывает только символы или символы и пути? В первом случае велика вероятность, что отладочной информации всё же нет...

Comment: Библиотека своя и я точно уверен что отладочная информация там есть

Comment: проверь наличие ".debug_*" секций в elf'е библиотеки... можно например с помощью `readelf -S /path/to/libmy.so | grep debug`... если их нет, то тогда просто пересобери и удостоверься, что собираешь с ключом `-g`... после этого скорей всего заработает из коробки если исходники либы не двигать...

Comment: Не двигать исходники? А если библиотека у меня лежит в скажем в ё.usr/bin/`, а исходники я скачиваю с репозитория при необходимости, есть ли возможность их сопоставить?

Comment: есть, но это потребует дополнительных телодвижений ([см. для gdb](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Source-Path.html#Source-Path) ) и при наличии исходников обычно проще пересобрать ИМХО, заодно будешь уверен, что версия библиотеки в точности соответствует исходникам...